# JPA Criteria Query: how to automatically create LEFT JOIN instead of WHERE conditions

Tags: jpa, left-join, criteria-api

I have two entity:

```
public class public class Person implements Serializable {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8729624892493146858L;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    ...

    @JoinColumn(name = "idcity",referencedColumnName = "id",nullable = true)
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = City.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private City city
    ...
}
```

and the related entity (extract):

```
public class City{
    Long id;
    String name;
    ...
}
```

Now i'm creating a criteria query in a standard way, querying the Person class:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery(selectClass);        
Root<T> root  = query.from(this.entityClass);
Selection selezioni[] = new Selection[selections.length];
for(int i=0; i< selections.length; i++){
        selezioni[i] = CriteriaHelper.getField(selections[i], cb, root);
}
query.select(cb.construct(selectClass, selezioni));
```

where entityClass is Person and selection and selectClass are used to compile the SELECT clause. In the select i've person.city.name field.

This system create a query with where clause:

```
select person.name, ..., city.name from person, city WHERE person.idcity = city.id...
```

but city is not required, so the records without city are not fetched.

Without changing all my automatic system, does exists a simpler way to force the use on LEFT JOIN for the relationship than adding a system to create root.join("field",LEFT)?

Note: the method CriteriaHelper.getField() return a Path starting from the root object

Comment: Why do you use EAGER fetching? :-)

Comment: Try using an OR condition that will generate it like this `(person.idcity = city.id OR city.id IS NULL)`. Because on the joins where there is no right side, it will be null. I used such queries in PostgreSQL and MySQL, but I'm not experienced enough with CriteriaQuery to write that up as an answer.

Comment: @galovics because i need to return it via a REST web service, so i serialize it via jackson. If i use LAZY fetching, the related entity results not in the entity manager